# pyinstaller cannot open 'EndUpdateResourceW'

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I tried to compile my app after updating pyinstaller, and it seems to run into this weird error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py", line 35, in pywin32error
    yield
  File "C:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\win32api.py", line 229, in EndUpdateResource
    _resource._EndUpdateResource(handle, discard)
  File "C:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\ctypes\_util.py", line 64, in check_false
    raise make_error(function, function_name)
OSError: [WinError 110] The system cannot open the device or file specified.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 178, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 59, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 842, in main
    build(specfile, distpath, workpath, clean_build)
  File "C:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 764, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "app.spec", line 30, in <module>
    exe = EXE(
  File "C:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 524, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "C:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 173, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "C:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 692, in assemble
    self.manifest.update_resources(build_name, [1])
  File "C:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winmanifest.py", line 904, in update_resources
    UpdateManifestResourcesFromXML(dstpath, self.toprettyxml().encode("UTF-8"), names, languages)
  File "C:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winmanifest.py", line 992, in UpdateManifestResourcesFromXML
    winresource.UpdateResources(dstpath, xmlstr, RT_MANIFEST, names or [name], languages or [0, "*"])
  File "C:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winresource.py", line 189, in UpdateResources
    win32api.EndUpdateResource(hdst, 0)
  File "C:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\win32api.py", line 229, in EndUpdateResource
    _resource._EndUpdateResource(handle, discard)
  File "C:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\contextlib.py", line 135, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py", line 37, in pywin32error
    raise error(exception.winerror, exception.function, exception.strerror)
win32ctypes.pywin32.pywintypes.error: (110, 'EndUpdateResourceW', 'The system cannot open the device or file specified.')
```

Anyone ran into similar problems? I updated pyinstaller because I was running into issues with the google core hook, now that worked but this became an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation:

```
win32ctypes.pywin32.pywintypes.error: (110, 'EndUpdateResource', 'The system cannot open the device or file specified')
```

I also got it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem.
Just stop DropBox sync - and problem was solved.

Comment: Could you give more details to why "DropBox sync" would be causing the issue?